# GStreamer: capture 2 rtsp stream from ip camera

Tags: video, gstreamer, rtsp

I need to crate pipeline with gstreamer for capture the two rtsp streams (main stream with audio and sub stream no audio) synchronized. It is important that they start at the same time and without video compression.

The command I'm currently using is

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.5.22/1 protocols=tcp ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=/home/pi/NAS/main.ts -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.5.22/1 protocols=tcp ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=/home/pi/NAS/sub.ts
```

This command works discreetly however the audio is not present because the pcm_alaw codec is not supportedin ts file.
The container must be mpegts The  need to convert the audio but I can't

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, did you found any solution? i have a similar problem

Comment: no, I converted my code using ffmpeg. Sorry